# Exibir erros PHP MySQL corretamente

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho um formulário de cadastro simples, onde não podem existir registros repetidos no campo `cpf` e também no campo `resposta(cupom)`. A validação do `cpf` está ok e os dados não duplicam no MySQL, mas a verificação e retorno dos erros está falha. Segue o código:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conecta.php'); ?>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0 );
error_reporting(0);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
$data = date("Y-m-d");

function validaCPF($cpf)
{   // Verifiva se o número digitado contém todos os digitos
$cpf = str_pad(ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $cpf), 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
// Verifica se nenhuma das sequências abaixo foi digitada, caso seja, retorna falso
if (strlen($cpf) != 11 || $cpf == '00000000000' || $cpf == '11111111111' || $cpf == '22222222222' || $cpf == '33333333333' || $cpf == '44444444444' || $cpf == '55555555555' || $cpf == '66666666666' || $cpf == '77777777777' || $cpf == '88888888888' || $cpf == '99999999999')
{
return false;
}
else
{ // Calcula os números para verificar se o CPF é verdadeiro
for ($t = 9; $t < 11; $t++) {
for ($d = 0, $c = 0; $c < $t; $c++) {
$d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);
}

$d = ((10 * $d) % 11) % 10;

if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
return false;
}
}

return true;
}
}
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

$resposta = $_POST['resposta'];


$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membros WHERE cpf = '$cpf' OR resposta = '$resposta'");
if(@mysql_num_rows($search) >= 1){
echo '<p align="center">Registro não efetuado!<br /> Cada CPF ou Cupom, só pode ser cadastrado uma vez. O CPF precisa ser válido.</p>';
}
elseif ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    if(isset($_POST['btvalidar']))
{// Adiciona o numero enviado na variavel $cpf_enviado, poderia ser outro nome, e executa a função acima
$cpf_enviado = validaCPF($_POST['cpf']);
// Verifica a resposta da função e exibe na tela
if($cpf_enviado == true) {
echo "CPF Válido";
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO membros (id, nome, cpf, email, resposta, data) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nome'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cpf'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['resposta'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['data'], "date"));

  mysql_select_db($database_conecta, $conecta);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conecta) or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<p align="center">Registro efetuado com sucesso!</p>';
}
elseif($cpf_enviado == false)
echo "CPF Inválido.";
}

}

// Verifica se o botão de validação foi acionado

/*function srange ($s) {
  //preg_match_all("/([0-9]{1,2})-?([0-9]{0,2}) ?,?;?/", $s, $a);
  $n = array ();
  foreach ($a[1] as $k => $v) {
    $n  = array_map(function($n) { return sprintf('RS%03d', $n); }, range(0000001, 1000000));
  }
  return ($n);
}

$s = 'RS0000001-RS1000000';
print_r(srange($n));*/
//$k = array(range(1000000,9000000));



// print_r($k);    

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaCampo()
{
if(document.form1.nome.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo nome é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
    else
    if(document.form1.cpf.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo CPF é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.form1.email.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo email é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
    else
    if(document.form1.resposta.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Cupom é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.form1.telefone.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Telefone é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.form1.bairro.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Bairro é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.form1.pais.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo país é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.form1.login.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Login é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else    
if(document.form1.senha.value=="")
    {
    alert("Digite uma senha!");
    return false;
    }
else
return true;
}
<!-- Fim do JavaScript que valida os campos obrigatórios! -->
</script>

<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Nome:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nome" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Cpf:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cpf" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Email:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Resposta:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="resposta" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="btvalidar" type="submit" id="btvalidar" value="Inserir registro" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

E a tabela MySQL:

```
--
-- Estrutura para tabela `membros`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `membros` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `resposta` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cpf` (`cpf`),
  UNIQUE KEY `resposta` (`resposta`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;

--
-- Fazendo dump de dados para tabela `membros`
--

INSERT INTO `membros` (`id`, `nome`, `email`, `cpf`, `data`, `resposta`) VALUES
(32, 'Marcos Felipe', 'email@hotmail.com', '22554477889', '2014-09-26', 'RS0000001'),
(33, 'Marcos Felipe', 'email@hotmail.com', '02545596985', '2014-09-26', 'RS0000002');
```

Comment: Se quiser exibir os erros do código deixe o `display_errors` como `true` e o `error_reporting` como `E_ALL`. Poderia dar mais detalhes dessa falha?

Comment: Por exemplo, se tento inserir um cpf duplicado, ao invés de mostrar o erro "Registro não efetuado!<br /> Cada CPF ou Cupom, só pode ser cadastrado uma vez. O CPF precisa ser válido." é exibido a mensagem de erro padrão do mysql "Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'cpf'"

Comment: No localhost está funcionando, mas quando sobe pra hospedagem, não da certo.

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando na hospedagem? `ereg_*` por exemplo foi depreciada no php5.3.

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: Veja na consulta se `$cpf` ou `$resposta` não estão indo com espaços, use `trim()` para remove-los.

Comment: Nada, os dados vão corretamente e quando o mysql percebe a duplicidade, retorna o erro "Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'cpf'" e não insere os dados, o que é correto, não pode duplicar. Mas eu queria que mostrasse o erro que está no código php e não o padrão do mysql.

Answer (score 3):

O que está acontecendo é que no servidor atual a coluna CPF está com `unique`, portanto o MySQL não está deixando inserir os dados. Se você remover o `unique` do índice, seu `if` original de teste funcionará.

Se você quer personalizar os erros e manter o `unique`, **o que é o caminho ideal**, deve tirar a linha com o `die()` que é a que põe o erro original na tela, e usar algo deste tipo no lugar:

```
$Result1 = mysql_query( ... query desejada ... ); // mysqli_query($con, query)

$erro = mysql_errno(); // mysqli_errno($con); para mysqli, é ideal trocar o quanto antes.

if ($erro == 0) {
    echo '<p align="center">Registro efetuado com sucesso!</p>';
} elseif ($erro == 1062) { // ou 1586, teste. Verifique a versão do MySQL usado
    echo '<p align="center">Esse CPF ou Mensagem já existe(m) na base de dados</p>';
} elseif ($erro == 2) {    // Este é só um exemplo, personalize como quiser:
    echo '<p align="center">Erro personalizado 2</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p align="center">Erro MySQL #'.$erro.'</p>';
}
```

Aí basta personalizar as mensagens para os erros desejados com os `elseif` necessários comparando com os **[códigos de erro do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry_with_key_name)**.

De "brinde", com essa solução você pode eliminar o `SELECT` extra que usa atualmente só para testar essa condição.

**Nota:** este exemplo serve bem para o caso do `unique` ser apenas no CPF e Mensagem. Se tiver mais colunas `unique`, ponha uma mensagem mais ampla no `elseif`, ou verifique qual foi a coluna que disparou o respectivo erro.

<sub>E aproveite pra consertar o seu código urgentemente usando funções `mysqli_` em vez daquele improviso com `function exists`</sub>

Comment: Deu certo, segue a solução:

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo, segue a solução:

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conecta); //or die(mysql_error());
  if ($erro == 0) {
    echo '<p align="center">Registro efetuado com sucesso!</p>';
}
  elseif (mysql_errno() == 1060)
{
    echo '<p align="center">Esse CPF ou Mensagem já existe(m) na base de dados.</p>'; // coloque a mensagem aqui
}
elseif (mysql_errno() == 1061)
{
    echo '<p align="center">Esse CPF ou Mensagem já existe(m) na base de dados.</p>'; // coloque a mensagem aqui
}
elseif (mysql_errno() == 1062)
{
    echo '<p align="center">Esse CPF ou Cupom já existe(m) na base de dados.</p>'; // coloque a mensagem aqui
}
```

Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Tenho que aprender muito ainda, mas aos poucos chegamos lá.