# Como exibir erro ao fazer query?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com o seguinte problema, esta query não está a inserir os dados no banco de dados:

```
$inserir2 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO cliques (emailusuario, brasil, lucrobrasil, portugal, lucroportugal, suica, lucrosuica, belgica, lucrobelgica, australia, lucroaustralia, africadosul, lucroafricadosul, franca, lucrofranca, mexico, lucromexico, tailandia, lucrotailandia, novazelandia, lucronovazelandia, colombia, lucrocolombia, argentina, lucroargentina, india, lucroindia, italia, lucroitalia, reinounido, lucroreinounido, outrospaises, lucrooutrospaises) VALUES ('$email', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000', '0', '0.000')");
```

Lembro-me que havia uma forma de mostrar o erro concreto.

Como poderei fazer para ela mostrar-me um erro, para dizer em que coluna estou a "errar"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O jeito usual é:

```
$inserir2 = mysqli_query( $link, $sql ) or die( mysqli_error( $link ) );
```

Se precisar de algo mais elaborado, tem como se obter o código do erro e sua descrição:

```
$inserir2 = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
if( !$inserir2 ) {
   echo 'Código de erro:'.mysqli_errno( $link ).'<br>';
   echo 'Mensagem de erro:'mysqli_error( $link ).'<br>';
}
```

Agora, isso faz mais sentido ao fazer o *debug* do código.

Provavelmente numa aplicação real, você **não deve jogar o erro na tela**, e sim fazer um log no sistema, ou gravar uma mensagem interna pros desenvolvedores do site, afinal, não faz sentido e nem é vantagem dar detalhes internos da sua aplicação para um usuário final (**ou potencial atacante/invasor**).

Veja um exemplo que grava uma mensagem no *log* do PHP:

```
if( ! ($inserir2 = mysqli_query( $link, $sql )) ) {
   error_log( 'Erro ao fazer query:'.mysqli_error( $link ) );
   // Aqui você deve fazer algo que seja adequado para o contexto,
   // dependendo da sua aplicação. O `die` é meramente ilustrativo,
   // e não vai encerrar corretamente seu HTML nem manter um layout
   // adequado na página. Num caso real, execute o cleanup necessário
   // para encerrar o script corretamente. 
   die( 'Ocorreu um problema ao atender sua solicitação' );
}
```

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-log.php

[Aqui tem mais um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34075/70) de uma maneira diferente de tratar os erros com base nos códigos numéricos.