# Erro de PHP com MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou com um erro e não entendi porque.
O erro:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean`

o trecho do erro:

```
require 'conecta.php';
    $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `endereco` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = Caxias do Sul";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<article>' . $linha['nomep'];
        $nome = $linha['nomep'];
        echo '</article>';
    }
```

O estranho é que o erro só acontece quando eu coloco o `WHERE`cidade`= Caxias do Sul";`

Comment: Ahh, sim agora eu vi o erro e já corrigi. Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Um `if( !$result ) die( mysqly_error( $mysqli ) );` basta para testar erros, mas não use o código em produção. Mais detalhes aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141797/70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é porque `mysqli_query` `FALSE`, por isso no erro aparece `BOLEAN` (que não é o tipo esperado para `fetch_assoc`).

A causa é que **Caxias do Sul** é uma string e tem que está entre aspas. Deveria estar assim: `'Caxias do Sul'`.

Altere de:

```
$sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `endereco` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = Caxias do Sul";
```

Para:

```
 $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `endereco` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = 'Caxias do Sul'";
```