# Problema ao dá update em uma table php sem nenhum retorno

Tags: php, mysqli, post, sql-update

Eu não tenho retorno nenhum na página quando clico no input com name['editar'] mesmo com os try catch, a página não imprime nada, por isso não sei o que fazer direito, queria saber o que estou fazendo de errado, todas as variaveis como $nome e $email estão sendo atualizadas, na verdade o único retorno que tenho são as variáveis que usei o echo para ver se elas realmente estavam sendo atualizadas e estão

```
    <?php
include './conexao.php';
$editando= filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
if(isset($editando['editar'])){

    echo $id = $editando['idEditar'];
   echo $nome = $editando['nomeEditar'];
   echo $email = $editando['emailEditar'];
    echo $site = $editando['siteEditar'];
    echo $data = $editando['dataEditar'];
    echo  $telefone = $editando['telefoneEditar'];
    echo $cidade = $editando['cidadeEditar'];
    echo $estado = $editando['estadoEditar'];
  $update_Query = "UPDATE cliente_tb SET nomeCliente = '".$nome."', emailCliente ='".$email."', siteCliente = '".$site."', dataContratacao = '".$data."',  telefone = '$".$telefone."', cidadeCliente ='".$cidade."', estadoCliente = '".$estado."' WHERE id = '".$id."' "; 
  try{
        $update_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $update_Query);         
        if($update_Result){
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Dados Atualizados';
            }else{
                echo 'Dados não foram atualizados';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Nao entrou no update result';

        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Update '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}else{
    echo 'Não está entrando no isset';
}
?>
```

Comment: Veja aqui [como exibir erro ao fazer query com mysqli](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141796/70)

Comment: Obrigado! foi bem útil

Comment: Usando o link que o Bacco me enviou nos comentários consegui resolver vendo o erro da query! Obrigado

Comment: Fechei como duplicata para organizar, qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário aqui.