# (PHP) Qual variavel eu coloco dentro do mysqli_affected_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
  <?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","banco");

$nome = isset($_REQUEST['nome'])?$_REQUEST['nome']:"";
$telefone = isset($_REQUEST['telefone'])?$_REQUEST['telefone']:"";
$sql = "insert into tb_banco(nome, telefone)values('$nome','$telefone')";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

$registro = mysqli_affected_rows($salvar);

if($registro==0){
    echo "telefone já cadastrado,use outro";
}else{
    echo "Cadastro realizado com sucesso";
}

?>
```

Comment: O código parece certo. A comparação deveria ser `$registro >= 1`.

Comment: @rray mas o código esta errado sim, INSERT não vai checar se existem outros telefones, no `mysqli_affected_rows` só vai retornar quantos inseriu, vai ser sempre 0 ou 1, pois só tem um insert, 0 para acaso não consiga inserir.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se ela tiver um indice unique, o código está perfeito - inclusive é a maneira correta de fazer, e não o clássico código errado que todo mundo usa "select pra ver se existe, insert em seguida"  (tirando o problema do $salvar, onde devia ser $conexao) - Eventualmente ela poderia checar pelo erro 1062 em vez de verificar o affected, só para a eventualidade de diferenciar outros erros.

Comment: @Bacco Boa!! vale questionar diretamente a AP :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bem notado, o insert até pode fazer isso SE o telefone tiver um índice único. Me apeguei no título da pergunta já não nenhum outro texto explicado o problema xD

Comment: É esse caso aqui: [Como não repetir valor no MySql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23014/70) - complemento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34075/70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do PHP em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-affected-rows.php:

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

É uma função que retorna um valor inteiro contendo "o número de linhas afetadas pelo último `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` ou `DELETE` associado ao **link_identifier**."

**link_identifier**: por sua vez é a conexão com o banco mysql. Esse argumento não é obrigatório quando você apenas tiver uma conexão com banco MySQL.

Trazendo isso para seu exemplo ficaria:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","banco");

$nome = isset($_REQUEST['nome'])?$_REQUEST['nome']:"";
$telefone = isset($_REQUEST['telefone'])?$_REQUEST['telefone']:"";
$sql = "insert into tb_banco(nome, telefone)values('$nome','$telefone')";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

$registro = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

if($registro==0){
    echo "telefone já cadastrado,use outro";
}else{
    echo "Cadastro realizado com sucesso";
}
```